# Is it possible to have a batch job run in a modal

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, batch-operations

I created a form that on submit it creates a CSV file via batch API. It works perfectly when submitting the form regularly but can't get it to work from a Ctools modal.

Could it be that it just isn't possible because of the ajax?

Comment: Out of the box this is not possible. If a bit of custom code is acceptable, https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/drupal-8-running-batch-through-ajax-request could provide a solution.